# DirectMessageListenerContainer: How to handle queue deletion in RabbitMQ?

Tags: spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-amqp

I am using `DirectMessageListenerContainer` to consume data from RabbitMQ. The following is my scenario:

I have two modules which interact with RabbitMQ. First module creates and deletes the queue whereas second module has `DirectMessageListenerContainer` which listens to the queues in RabbitMQ.

Whenever any queue is deleted in RabbitMQ, the `DirectMessageListenerContainer` starts to throw exception continuously and tries to connect to the already deleted queue.

My question is, is there any way where i can handle the exception and perform my operation over that?

Answer (score 1):

When you delete queues in one module, you can schedule unsubscribtions from those queues in the container. See its method:

```
/**
 * Remove queue(s) from this container's list of queues.
 * @param queueNames The queue(s) to remove.
 * @return the boolean result of removal on the target {@code queueNames} List.
 */
public boolean removeQueueNames(String... queueNames) {
```

You can also just subscribe to the `ListenerContainerConsumerFailedEvent` application even via `@EventiListener` in the second module to perform the same `removeQueueNames`. I think `Throwable` of that `ListenerContainerConsumerFailedEvent` should have some information what queue is bad to consume at the moment.

Comment: Hi Artem, I tried the approach `@Component public class HandleQueueDeletion { @EventListener public void handleListenerFailure(ListenerContainerConsumerFailedEvent evt){ logger.error("Listener failure event: " + evt.getReason()); } }` i still get the error from `DirectMessageListenerContainer` as `Queue not present, scheduling consumer SimpleConsumer [queue=ABC, consumerTag=null identity=56b30888] for restart`. Can you please provide any suggestions here?

Answer (score 1):

```
    boolean queueRemovedFromListener = false;
    DirectMessageListenerContainer listener = (DirectMessageListenerContainer) 
                registry.getListenerContainer("listener");
        List<String> queueNamesList = Arrays.asList(listener.getQueueNames());
        if(queueNamesList.contains(queueName)) {
            queueRemovedFromListener = listener.removeQueueNames(queueName);
        }
        if(queueRemovedFromListener) {
            Map<String, Object> arguments = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            Binding binding = new Binding(queueName, DestinationType.QUEUE, exchangeName, queueName,
                    arguments);
            rabbitAdmin.removeBinding(binding);
            rabbitAdmin.deleteQueue(queueName, false, true);
        }
```

As suggested in previous answer you can pass queuename and exchange name as inputs and using removeQueueNames method you will be able to remove the queue from listener and delete the queue without getting any excpetions.